# Question related to Agent skills in salesforce live Agent set up?

Tags: liveagent, livechattranscript

Can any one help me out what was the exact difference between Assigning skills to user and Assignnign in skills to profile.look at the Screen shot below for your reference

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have the same function but doing it at the profile level scales better